# Get Number of Documents in MongoDB Index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

As per the title, I would like to know if there is a way to get the number of documents in a MongoDB index.

To be clear, I am **not** looking for either of the following:

- How to get the number of documents in a *collection* -- `.count()`.
- How to get the *size* of an index -- `.stats()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An index references all of the documents in its collection unless the index is a [sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) or a [partial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/). From the docs:

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value. The index skips over any document that is missing the indexed field. The index is “sparse” because it does not include all documents of a collection. By contrast, **non-sparse indexes contain all documents in a collection**, storing null values for those documents that do not contain the indexed field.
>
> Partial indexes only index the documents in a collection that meet a specified filter expression

So ...

- The answer for non sparse and non partial indexes is `db.collection.count()`
- The answer for sparse and partial indexes *could* be inferred by running a query with no criteria, hinting on that index and then counting the results. For example:

  ```
    db.collection.find().hint('index_name_here').count()
  ```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/), too. They would fall in the same category as sparse ones, though.

Comment: Also, for sparse/partial indexes I would recommend looking at the definition and issuing a count query for the filter criteria rather than going down the hint path.

Comment: @dnickless good call re partial indexes, I have updated the answer, thanks.